# Properly import com.intellij.ide.util.projectWizard.JavaModuleBuild

Tags: java, kotlin, gradle, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I am able to properly import `com.intellij.ide.util.projectWizard.ModuleBuilder` and many other imports from this package, however I cannot import `com.intellij.ide.util.projectWizard.JavaModuleBuilder` without setting the module SDK to the intellij platform one in project structure, however due to this being a gradle project, when i reimport gradle, that just reverts. Here is my build.gradle

```kotlin
plugins {
    id("org.jetbrains.intellij").version("0.6.5")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm").version("1.4.30")
}

group 'org.aj3douglas'
version '1.0.0'

repositories { mavenCentral() }

// See https://github.com/JetBrains/gradle-intellij-plugin/
intellij {
    pluginName = project.name
    version '2020.2.3'
    type 'IJ'
    downloadSources true
}
patchPluginXml {
    changeNotes """"""
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Java-related classes were extracted in a dedicated plugin in SDK 2019.2:

https://blog.jetbrains.com/platform/2019/06/java-functionality-extracted-as-a-plugin/

You're targeting SDK 2020.2.3, which means you need to add the Java plugin in your `intellij` section:

```
intellij {
  plugins = ['com.intellij.java']
  // ...
}
```